# rollover image for form

Tags: image, forms, rollovers

Is it possible to have a rollover effect for an image and a form.

I.e. I would like to have an image, which when the user hovers over, rolls away to reveal a form (like a login or sign up form).

Cant find anything out like there like this so assuming its not possible but thought I'd ask!

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much possible.

Using CSS, say position: absolute for the image and the form's div.

Then using z-index, make sure that the image lies over the form.

Then you can use the HTML onmouseover event to execute something like a call to Adobe Spry's slide animation effect to neatly accomplish what you're trying to do.

But in my honest opinion, this is unnecessary glitter.